# El programa con funciones no se ejecuta, ¿por que?

Tags: python, funciones

He estado intentando que se ejecute (que seguramente algo mal estaré haciendo), sin embargo a la hora de ejecutarlo solo me muestra la ubicación del archivo, no mas que eso, he intentado hacer las funciones fuera del programa, luego dentro y asi sucesivamente pero no entiendo muy bien en donde estará el error, si alguien me pudiese explicar le agradeceria mucho:)

```
def suma(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
    result = suma(num1, num2)

def resta(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2
    result = resta(num1, num2)

def multiplicacion(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2
    result = multiplicacion(num1, num2)

def division(num1, num2):
    return  num1 / num2
    result = division(num1, num2)
    opcion1 = -1
    while opcion1 != 0:
         print (""" MENU
    1. Suma
    2. Resta
    3. Multiplicacion
    4. División
    5. SALIR
    """)
    opcion1 = int(input("Por favor ingrese una opcion: "))
    num1 = float(input("Ingrese el primer numero: "))
    num2 = float(input("Ingrese el segundo numero: "))
    if opcion1 == 1:
        suma()
    elif opcion1 == 2:
        resta()
    elif opcion1 == 3:
        multiplicacion()
    elif opcion1 == 4:
        division()
    elif opcion1 == 5:
        print("Gracias, vuelva pronto.")
    else:
        print("Numero inválido.")
```

Comment: El código que muestras **define** las funciones, pero mientras no las **llames** su código no se ejecuta. ¿Las llamas desde otro módulo o es lo que has mostrado todo lo que tienes? Por otro lado parece que hay un error lógico. Si no me equivoco todo el código tras el `while` debería estar fuera de la función `division` y no dentro. Aunque pudiera tratarse de un error al copiar y pegar el código en Stack Overflow

Comment: Para asegurarte de que al copiar y pegar no estropeas la indentación, es mejor que uses el triple backtick ``` antes del código y otro ``` después del código. Y en medio de ambos pegas tu código desde el editor _sin tocarlo_.

Answer (score 1):

Es importante recordar que en Python **la indentación es relevante**, pues es lo que define los bloques de instrucciones.

También debes recordar a llamar las funciones `suma, resta, etc` pasando los dos valores con que deben operar. Y, desde luego, capturar el resultado de la función para mostrarlo. Fijate que después de un `return` ya no se ejecuta (afortunadamente, pues tienes una llamada recursiva a la misma función).

Por último, el patrón a usar para estos ciclos es un `while True:`, colocando un `break` condicional dentro del cuerpo. También debes chequear primero la condición de término y salir. Tal como está, siempre pides los dos valores, incluso cuando el usuario elige salir:

En resumen:

```
def suma(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2


def resta(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2


def multiplicacion(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2


def division(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2


while True:
    print(
        """ MENU
            1. Suma
            2. Resta
            3. Multiplicacion
            4. División
            5. SALIR
        """)

    opcion1 = int(input("Por favor ingrese una opcion: "))
    if opcion1 == 5:
        print("Gracias, vuelva pronto.")
        break

    num1 = float(input("Ingrese el primer numero: "))
    num2 = float(input("Ingrese el segundo numero: "))

    if opcion1 == 1:
        resultado = suma(num1, num2)
    elif opcion1 == 2:
        resultado = resta(num1, num2)
    elif opcion1 == 3:
        resultado = multiplicacion(num1, num2)
    elif opcion1 == 4:
        resultado = division(num1, num2)
    else:
        print("Numero inválido.")
        continue

    print(f"resultado = {resultado}")
```

produce:

```
 MENU
            1. Suma
            2. Resta
            3. Multiplicacion
            4. División
            5. SALIR
        
Por favor ingrese una opcion: 1
Ingrese el primer numero: 2
Ingrese el segundo numero: 3
resultado = 5.0
 MENU
            1. Suma
            2. Resta
            3. Multiplicacion
            4. División
            5. SALIR
        
Por favor ingrese una opcion: 2
Ingrese el primer numero: 4
Ingrese el segundo numero: 2
resultado = 2.0
 MENU
            1. Suma
            2. Resta
            3. Multiplicacion
            4. División
            5. SALIR
        
Por favor ingrese una opcion: 3
Ingrese el primer numero: 2
Ingrese el segundo numero: 6
resultado = 12.0
 MENU
            1. Suma
            2. Resta
            3. Multiplicacion
            4. División
            5. SALIR
        
Por favor ingrese una opcion: 4
Ingrese el primer numero: 4
Ingrese el segundo numero: 3
resultado = 1.3333333333333333
```